# Как вывести на барплот значение, которое сильно меняет свой порядок от начала до конца временного ряда

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, графики

Требуется, чтобы на большм диапазоне данных было видно начальные бары. Т.е. условно, значение растет от 10 до 1 млн на нескольких временных точках по x. Как сделать, чтобы первые бары графика были хорошо читаемы (не сливались с нулем) и при этом выводилось их фактическое значение по оси y.?

Нужно получить что-то вроде такого графика, только укрупнить столбцы в начале. Чтобы они не сливались в линию. Плюс в 1-2-3 барах есть отрицательные значения, которые должно быть хорошо видно ниже линии 0.

```
x = ['2022','2023','2024','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030']
y = [45, 3792, 33708, 251604, 605088, 919392, 1233696, 1548000, 1862304]
y2 = [-7168, -13044, -10928, 77554, 348029, 598680, 849331, 1099982, 1351329]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Как примерно должны быть расположены бары]

Comment: логарифмические оси

Comment: вы логарифмическую шкалу изобрести пытаетесь?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я пробовал делать с использованием yaxis_type="log" в Plotly. Это не принесло нужного результата. Также не нашел похожих примеров кода.

Comment: Тогда срочно в школу, там насколько помню в старших классах это проходится :)

Answer (score 2):

если данные меняются постепенно на всем протяжении временного интервала, то должно помочь использование логарифмических или кастомных шкал. примеры смотрите [здесь](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-scales-py).

ну а если это просто отдельные выбросы, которые вы хотите тоже показать, то есть еще вариант с разорванной шкалой. пример [здесь](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-broken-axis-py).

**UPD**

еще, как вариант, можно разбить данные на несколько интервалов и для каждого задать свою шкалу. примерно вот так (хотя это равносильно тому, чтобы построить несколько отдельных графиков):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'melon', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange', 'mango', 'tomato', 'peach']
counts = [-1, 3, 4, 40, 30, 55, 1000, 1500, 1800]
s = pd.Series(counts,index=fruits)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))

twin1 = ax.twinx()
twin2 = ax.twinx()
twin2.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.05))

b1 = ax.bar(s[s<10].index, s[s<10], color='b', label='low')
b2 = twin1.bar(s[(10<=s)&(s<100)].index, s[(10<=s)&(s<100)], color='g', label='midle')
b3 = twin2.bar(s[s>=100].index, s[s>=100], color='r', label='high')

ax.bar_label(b1, padding=-20, color='w')
twin1.bar_label(b2, padding=-20, color='w')
twin2.bar_label(b3, padding=-20, color='w')

ax.set_xlabel("fruits")
ax.set_ylabel("low_total")
twin1.set_ylabel("mid_total")
twin2.set_ylabel("hi_total")

ax.yaxis.label.set_color('b')
twin1.yaxis.label.set_color('g')
twin2.yaxis.label.set_color('r')

ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='b', size=4, width=1.5)
twin1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='g', size=4, width=1.5)
twin2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='r', size=4, width=1.5)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', size=4, width=1.5)

ax.legend(handles=[b1, b2, b3], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2**

если применить этот подход к вашим данным, то можно получить что-то вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но как по мне, этот график не только сильно перегружен, но и совсем не наглядный

Comment: Мне не кажется, что логарифмические шкалы - это не совсем то решение, которое нужно. Хотя бы потому, что мне нужно на оси Y указывать фактические значения, а не логарифмы. 

Нужно просто более крупно показать часть бар графика, чего логарифмические шкалы опять же не решают так, как требуется, чтобы на итоговой визуализации был виден каждый сегмент, независимо от того какого порядка значение он отражает. Т.е. не столько важно отношение значений столбцов и их 'длина' относительно друг друга, сколько удобство восприятия. 

Похоже, проще нарисовать такой график в пейнте:)

Comment: @user532719, нарисуйте и добавьте график в ваш вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотите получить, тогда может быть вам подскажут как это можно сделать с помощью python

Comment: Спасибо, так и поступил:)

Comment: цифирьки, по которым нарисован график, приведите в вопросе

Comment: @user532719, вы рисунок добавили, но из него не ясно, что же вы хотите получить в итоге, как должен выглядеть результат.

Comment: SergFSM, добавил рисунок - пример того, как я вижу результат. Нарисовал как мог, извините.

Comment: @user532719 цифирьки-то приведите, по которым строите, что ж народу их придумывать для тестов

Comment: splash58, так есть же там циферки

Comment: Извините, прозевал обновление :)

Answer (score 2):

В `matplotlib` вот достаточно выбрать правильную шкалу (симметричную логарифмическую) чтобы получить что-то наподобие нужного вам:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = ['2022','2023','2024','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030']
y = [45, 3792, 33708, 251604, 605088, 919392, 1233696, 1548000, 1862304]
y2 = [-7168, -13044, -10928, 77554, 348029, 598680, 849331, 1099982, 1351329]

plt.bar(x, y, color='b')
plt.bar(x, y2, color='r')
plt.yscale('symlog')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более "человеческую" шкалу можно сделать так:

```
from matplotlib import ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
...
plt.yscale('symlog')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%d"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, это действительно близко к цели. А можно как-то заменить значения Y на фактические столбцов вместо логарифмов?

Comment: Добавил более человеческий вариант шкалы.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Добавил, откуда собственно взялась `ax` там, а то непонятно было

Comment: А я разобрался :)

Answer (score 1):

самая первая ссылка в том ответе дает вот такой результат. мне кажется, это примерно то, что вы хотите. метки можете по оси можете сделать другие

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'y2': y2})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.x, df.y - df.y2, bottom=df.y2)
ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(lambda x: np.sign(x)*np.abs(x)**(1/2), lambda x: np.sign(x)*np.abs(x)**2))
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, концептуально это лучшее решение на данный момент:) Xотелось бы конечно сделать в plotly. Более красиво и детализировано, для презентации.

Comment: да наверняка там что-то такое можно. просто я про него ниче не знаю за ненадобностью

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо вам

Answer (score 0):

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

years = ['2022','2023','2024','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030']

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years,
                y=[45, 3792, 33708, 251604, 605088, 919392, 1233696, 1548000, 1862304],
                name='Gross',
                marker_color='rgb(55, 83, 109)'
                ))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years,
                y=[-7168, -13044, -10928, 77554, 348029, 598680, 849331, 1099982, 1351329],
                name='Revenue',
                marker_color='rgb(26, 118, 255)'
                ))

fig.update_layout(
    title='График дохода',
    xaxis_tickfont_size=14,
    yaxis=dict(
        title='График дохода',
        titlefont_size=16,
        tickfont_size=14,
    ),
    legend=dict(
        x=0,
        y=1.0,
        bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
        bordercolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    ),
    barmode='group',
    bargap=0.15, # gap between bars of adjacent location coordinates.
    bargroupgap=0.1 # gap between bars of the same location coordinate.
)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[-14000,20000])
fig.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается похоже на желаемый вариант, если ограничивать значения оси Y (собственно сокращать диапазон данных).